# How to make a material box for an image in Vuetify

Tags: vuejs2, materialize, vuetify.js

I am trying to find a way to make material box present in [Materialize-CSS](https://materializecss.com/media.html) but id doesn't seem to be listed in the documentation. How can I do that?

Comment: It's different framework...

Comment: But is there a way to achieve something similar in Vuetify?

Comment: It's a Lightbox plugin implementation, and afaik vuetify doesn't have it implemented by default. So you can include it from somewhere else, or create your own version.

Comment: Ok, I’ll try to do it.